# Add a key to an exsting array in php (for rearranging an array)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to rearrange order of an array (`$activity_names`)

```
$next_ordernr = 1000;
foreach( $activity_names as $term_id=>$activityarea_name) {
    $onr = $custom_ordernrs[$term_id];
    if ((int)$onr === 0) {$onr = $next_ordernr; $next_ordernr++;}
    $activity_names[$term_id]['reorder']= $onr;
}
```

I understand how I should do it, but I'm kind of stuck when trying to add a key to an existing array (which should be the easy part ;-)).

I get this warning:

> `Warning: Illegal string offset 'reorder' in ...`.

The 'reorder' key does not exist before, but I thought I could like above just to add the key reorder into that existing array.

```
$next_ordernr = 1000;
foreach( $activity_names as $term_id=>$activityarea_name) {
    $onr = $custom_ordernrs[$term_id];
    if ((int)$onr === 0) {$onr = $next_ordernr; $next_ordernr++;}
    $activity_names[$term_id]= $onr;
}
```

Works as expected.

I just want to add a key to an existing array. What am I overlooking?

**UPDATE**
$`activity_names` array could look like this:

```
$activity_names[24] = 'Activityname1';
$activity_names[36] = 'Activityname2';
$activity_names[14] = 'Activityname3';
$activity_names[54] = 'Activityname4';
$activity_names[104] = 'Activityname5';
```

**UPDATE2**
When thinking of it, I am maybe approaching this incorrectly...
I want to rearrange order of `$activity_names` array based on `$custom_ordernrs` - array

The `$activity_names` and `$custom_ordernrs` - array could look like this:

```
$activity_names[24] = 'Activityname1';
$activity_names[36] = 'Activityname2';
$activity_names[14] = 'Activityname3';
$activity_names[54] = 'Activityname4';
$activity_names[104] = 'Activityname5';

$custom_ordernrs[24] = 5;
$custom_ordernrs[36] = 4;
$custom_ordernrs[14] = 3;
$custom_ordernrs[54] = 2;
$custom_ordernrs[104] = 1;
```

should result in this order in array:

```
$activity_names[104] = 'Activityname5';
$activity_names[54] = 'Activityname4';
$activity_names[14] = 'Activityname3';
$activity_names[36] = 'Activityname2';
$activity_names[24] = 'Activityname1';
```

Comment: Looks like `$activity_names[$term_id]` is simply not an array. It is a string, I guess. Show the contents of `$activity_names` by `print_r($activity_names)`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - aha... now I understand the actual problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$activity_names['your_key']= $value;
```

Comment: hm.. kind of ... but I still need the term_id - index. like activity_names[14]['reorder'], activity_names[23]['reorder] etc...

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon the same issue...

Approached the issue in another way. I rearranged the `$custom_ordernrs`-array instead (instead of trying to add a key to existing array `$activity_names`) and based on that create a temporary array and then replaced `$activity_names` with that temporary - array:

```
asort($custom_ordernrs); //Sort from low to high and maintin indexes(keys)

$temp = array();
foreach($custom_ordernrs as $term_id=>$an) {                                
    $temp[$term_id] = $activity_names[$term_id];
}
$activity_names = $temp;
```